# Converting an configuration file to HTML

Tags: java, html, properties

I have a bunch of configuration files which are usually properties files which are opened from application and edited like notepad.Now the requirement is pick each property and find which HTML tag does it fit through and display the whole properties file as HTML page. 
For eg:

*Security.Properties file*

```
//This property checks if the user has already logged or not
//Possible values Y N

order.security.Login=Y
```

So the above property has two possible values Y N .The equivalent HTML format can be a radio button with Y N. Similarly if another property takes values 1,2, the HTML is Listbox with these two values.

I know this is little cumbersome but has to done.
Development is JAVA JAVASCRIPT VELOCITY
My idea is convert all properties files into XML then use XSLT to render as HTML.
I would like to hear more ideas including performance issues.

Comment: You need to know the metadata about each property's value set. Do you want it to be extracted from the comments?

Comment: Possibly Yes, I havent explored the ways yet .Just looking for some ideas.One thing is based on input value the tag has to be determined so definitely it has to be extracted from comments .Yeah now I have understood the problem is even more complex than I thought.Thanks

Comment: If it is a two state yes/no then you should use a checkbox not a radio group.

Comment: I cant see a way to do it if you have to parse the comments, unless the comments are very strict and regular (i.e., parse-able).

Answer (score 1):

I would define a XML file that lists every properties key, and for each, the way it will displayed in HTML.

```
<property key="order.security.Login">
    <display type="radio" values="Y,N" />
</property>
```

then if you want to display a Properties as an HTML file, just parse this XML file with XSLT, using the property key to match the right element and display well its content (with a XSL file that convert a <display type="radio"> into a list of <input type="radio">)

Dunno if it will fit to your app configuration, but that'll be my first idea to fit.

Comment: But please, don't reinvent the XML schema. There are Java tools available to build editors dinamically from XSD.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, XSLT seems like the way to go.

Comment: But the problem is there are about 1200 conf files which needs to be altered. Can this be scalable?

Comment: With the right templates and if your XML have similarly made, this would require only 1 XSLT sheet. XSLT is usually more efficient then DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

How about a small javadoc/c#doc:

```
//<desc>This property checks if the user has already logged or not
//Possible values Y N</desc>
//<type>YN</type>
order.security.Login=Y
```

Comment: What will be the next step after JavaDoc .The second part of the problem of determining HTML appropriate tag

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1200 files (wow) then I can't see any other way but to automate it.

If you can work out the possible values from the properties that are filled in then you could use a different solution.

So there can't be many values
If the current value is Y then the only possible answer is N same with true or false
If the value is a string other then you allow a string input.

You say you use Velocity so you model has access to full Java. 
Read your properties file into a Properties object from which you can get an Enumeration of all the keys. 
for all the values in the properties file build up your html using your velocity templates Velocity.

```
Map<String, YourHolderObject> velocityPropertiesValues = 
    new HashMap<>(String, YourHolderObject);

Properties properties = new Properties("your properties file")
Enumeration keys = properties .keys();

while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
  String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
  String value = (String)p.get(key);
//.......get YourHolderObject which can will have methods like isBoolean, 
// if it is then in velocity create radio buttons etc
}


//then in velocity use that enriched object to decide what html to generate 
#foreach ($key in $properties.keySet())
 #if($refreshed.get($key).isBoolean)
   //generate the radio buttons
 #elseif($refreshed.get($key).isYesNoList)
    //do something else
 #
#end
```

I am sure you get the idea. 
Don't rely on the syntax it is just code to try and explain a different way of looking at your problem. Hope it helps.
Shawn